# DocumentDB Rest API - create document needs id for new documents

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to use the DocumentDB Rest API to create a new document and autogenerate the id for me.

The [Create Document documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/documentdb/create-a-document) says that id is a required property of the body, but the node.js SDK and the Azure Portal Document Explorer will both generate ID's when no id is provided in the input.

Here's the response from the server:

```
{ code: 'BadRequest',
  message: 'Message: {"Errors":["The input content is invalid because the required properties - \'id; \' - are missing","The request payload is invalid. Ensure to provide a valid request pa
yload."]}\r\nActivityId: 6b718b3d-01bc-403f-82e6-266254aad952, Request URI: /apps/4c8d65d7-216b-46b4-abb7-52c1a0c7123f/services/0e58e0c6-ff02-4523-a94b-204abd0d2179/partitions/6bf7ec3e-d850
-440e-bbcb-50d949389f3e/replicas/131469737377192972p' }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed that the DocumentDB node.js SDK generates its own id's, this is not something handled by the database.

Here is the code that they use to generate unique id's, packaged for independent use:

```
function generateGuidId () {
  var id = "";

  for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
      id += getHexaDigit();
  }

  id += "-";

  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      id += getHexaDigit();
  }

  id += "-";

  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      id += getHexaDigit();
  }

  id += "-";

  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      id += getHexaDigit();
  }

  id += "-";

  for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
      id += getHexaDigit();
  }

  return id;

}

function getHexaDigit () {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 16).toString(16);
}
```

Comment: Wow, that code does not generate unique ids - it makes not attempt to prevent clashes by using something intrinsic to it's environment like a machine name and timestamp. The chances of a clash may be very small, but having seen this I wouldn't rely on it. Thanks!

Comment: I was comfortable using it only if I had an extra key/value pair in every query, in my case we were using a "type" key (e.g. `SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.id='????' AND c.type='location'`)  That sends the probability of issues with duplicates down even further.

Comment: that seems like a good idea, but is id forced to be unique anyway? I.e. as long as the code checks for an error due to a duplicate being created it can regenerate and try to insert again.

Comment: That would add a lot of cost and time to each write.  If you're trying to scale your app you would never want to do it this way.

Comment: A clash will be a very unlikely/never occurrence so simply trapping the exception and trying again with a new id value would mean there would be no overhead to this approach for the vast majority of cases.

Comment: I respectfully disagree with your logic.  Please feel free to experiment with this, as I did.

Answer (score 0):

DocumentDb supports two addressing modes SelfLink (a.ka. RID) and AltLink (a.k.a. named). SelfLink is server generated. 'id' property is an opportunity for named addressing (ex: /dbs/ToDoList/colls/items/docs/user1).

SDK just tries to fill them with UNIQ values in-case of unavailability. I suggest strongly to specify the name.